# How can i update updatepanel with out postpack ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

i have a gridview in updatePanel that i need to update  every interval of time

what i have found so far on updating `updatepanel` is :

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" OnLoad="Button1_Click">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>UpdatePanel</legend>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Panel created.">
             </asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"   
           OnClientClick="__doPostBack('UpdatePanel2', '');" Text="Button" />
            </fieldset>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this sub

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Label2.Text = "Refreshed at " & _
        DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Sub
```

though this works fine and update the panel but it `postback` the whole the page , you can tell when you see all the images reloading in another panel  , i'm planning to update this panel every second

**Question** is How can i update `UpdatePanel2` without affecting the other panel with the postback

**EDIT**

*Another Question* does any thing runs at the server side DO postback ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of NET 3.5 there is the [Web.UI.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx) control:

> Performs asynchronous or synchronous Web page postbacks at a defined interval.

It is able to work with [UpdatePanels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), ensures that data (e.g. ViewState and updated control values) is not lost, and is "just another WebForm control". However, the Timer *must* still cause a [partial] postback to go through the page life-cycle and rebind the grid again.

Depending on exact use-case, it may be better to use a *true* AJAX-approach to minimize the page life-cycle and data size overhead. (Telerik, DevExpress, and other 3rd-party libraries support "lightweight callbacks" for their Grid controls. Even more lightweight variants might include jqGrid.)

Comment: it postback the whole page , do you have any other opsion to just targeting the gridview

Comment: Thanks that looks good but how van i update the `updatepanel` using javascript

Comment: @MinaGabriel As would any WebControl that uses [partial] postbacks. I have included a link to using Update Panels. The most simple way is to put *both* the Grid and the Timer in the same Update Panel so that when the Timer postbacks it will result in a partial-page update and the Update Panel (and the Grid inside of it) will be updated.

Comment: @MinaGabriel The Timer control will do that (without custom needing JavaScript). In my experience it is best to create/have a special "Trigger" control. Although it is possible to manually invoke the appropriate `__doPostBack` magic, this requires a fair amount of knowledge about how ASP.NET-WebForms works to use correctly.

Comment: @MinaGabriel Internally the UI Timer will use `setTimeout` (or similar) and issue the appropriate `__doPostBack` to trigger a postback (the Script Manager will convert it into a partial postback as appropriate). This, however, is nicely encapsulated by the control/framework.